# printk() doesn't print in /var/log/messages

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

My OS Ubuntu 12.04. I wrote this Kernel Module and i use insmod and rmmod command but there isn't anything in /var/log messages. how can i fix this problem?

```
/*  
*  hello-1.c - The simplest kernel module.
*/
#include <linux/module.h>   /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h>   /* Needed for KERN_INFO */

int init_module(void)
{
   printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");

    /* 
    * A non 0 return means init_module failed; module can't be loaded. 
    */
    return 0;
 }

 void cleanup_module(void)
 {
   printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
 }
```

Comment: Try KERN_ALERT instead of KERN_INFO to see if this is because your log level is set too high.  You can also change your log level.

Comment: how can i change log level?

Comment: klogd -c n, where n is the level.  There are also other ways to set it.

Comment: `echo '7 7 7 7' > /proc/sys/kernel/printk` See: [kernel.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/sysctl/kernel.txt)

Answer (score 1):

Check whether **syslog** daemon process is running, since this is the process which copies printk messages from kernel ring/log message  buffer to **/var/log/messages** if I am correct. printk messages can be seen using **dmesg** utility/command or messages will be in /var/log/messages. If correct loglevel is set then printk messages will be displayed on the console right away, no need to use dmesg or no need to check in /var/log/messages. printk debug messages can also be part of **/var/log/syslog**.

Answer (score 0):

Modern Linux distributions don't use rsyslog (or any other syslog daemon) anymore. They rely on journald which is part of systemd, so the /var/log/messages file is missing and you have to use the journalctl command to read the system log.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should check that whether your module is properly loaded or not, by using  this command

```
lsmod | grep "hello-1" //hello-1 is the name of your module
```

Since you wrote a kernel module, which prints some message. The messages from kernel and its module can be found in /var/log/syslog or you can view these kind of messages using dmesg command.
As your module prints "Hello World 1.", you should use following command to see message from your module.

```
dmesg | grep "Hello World 1."
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for this in /etc/syslog.conf, the *.info... lines. These seem to control what gets logged via printk.

```
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
auth,authpriv.none;\
cron,daemon.none;\
mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages
```

I found that /proc/sys/kernel/printk only really controlled the console logging levels, not the logging to the file. And I guess check syslog is running too ;) We had exactly the same issue, KERN_INFO not going to log files and this fixed it. hth

Answer (score 0):

I tried to print the kernel buffer by typing the following command :
`dmesg`
This will print the data written in `printk`